# multiprocessing program form calculating lines in a file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand and implement multiprocessing in python.

As a sample project i am trying to calculate number of lines in a give file.

My computer is having 4 cores. so my aim is to supply different chunks of data to all the 4 cores and calculate the number of lines in 4 chunks individually ,and combine the sum of all the 4 outputs at the end.

But i am not under standing how to implement this

Currently I am using following code, but the problem is i declared a global variable "i" and for all the cores if there is a new line i am incrementing i value.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_line(j):
    return j+1

i=0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    global i
    with open('sampleSubmission.csv') as source_file:
        for l in source_file:
            i=process_line(i)
    print i
```

I want it in such a way that i need a separate variable for every core and i want to increment the variable when that particular core encounters a new line.

After completion of file processing , i want to add the all the separate variables to get the total number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code isn't doing anything in parallel. You're creating a `Pool`, but not using it.

It doesn't really make much sense to iterate over the file to pass the lines to the subprocesses either. You're already doing all the work of splitting up the file by lines in the main process (as part of the iteration on the file), so there's nothing for the worker processes to do.

What you might want to do instead is read the whole file into a single string, then use the pool to count the number of newlines in the file. (Note, this is still wildly inefficient, since the overhead of passing the characters will massively dominate the time spent comparing with `"\n"`, but it will at least be doing something somewhat useful in parallel.)

```
def worker(character):
    return character == "\n" # note, True is a fancy version of 1, False is 0

if __name__ = "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    with open('sampleSubmission.csv') as source_file:
        text = source_file.read() # read whole file into a string
    num_newlines = pool.map(worker, text) # strings are iterable, by character
    print num_newlines + 1 # number of lines is one more than the number of newlines
```

You might actually get useful performance out of somewhat similar code if you changed it to use chunks of the file instead of individual characters. Or you could let the worker processes read the file themselves (starting at a passed offset), rather than passing the file's text between the main process and the workers. I still doubt either of those approaches would be faster than just doing the work in a single process, but you might get a bit closer. IO doesn't parallelize over different CPU cores very well.